# How to get the XML parsed images into array and use the array in all view controllers using iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have an XML file in URL where i can parse the data and get the images from the XML file. But i don't know how to use the images in other view controllers. I got an idea to store the images in array, but how can i use the array of images in other view controllers. Is it possible to store the XML parsed images in array.Am i parsing the XML correctly? Kindly suggest me an idea.

**My XML Parser**

```
//egsBase.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface egsBase : NSObject{
IBOutlet UIImage *img;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImage *img;
@end

//egsBase.m

#import "egsBase.h"
@implementation egsBase
@synthesize  img;
@end

//egsXMLParser.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "egsBase.h"
@interface egsXMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
    NSMutableArray *tweets;
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    egsBase *currentTweet;
}
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSMutableArray *tweets;
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *) urlString;
@end

//egsXMLParser.m

#import "egsXMLParser.h"
@implementation egsXMLParser
@synthesize tweets;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString{
     tweets  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
     NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
     parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
     parser.delegate = self;
     [parser parse];
     return self;
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Products"]){
    currentTweet = [egsBase alloc];
 }
}

 -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"])
{
  currentTweet.img=[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:currentNodeContent]]]; [tweets addObject:currentTweet.img];
 }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
   currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you parsing this correctly? There are a lot of issues, some substantive, some more stylistic. First, a couple of substantive observations:

1. Your `foundCharacters` assumes that it will be called only once for each element. For something like a URL that will generally be true, but you're not guaranteed of this fact. It should just be appending characters to a string, and the subsequent storage of the final string and the clean up should happen in `didEndElement`.
2. Your `foundCharacter` is also storing results whether you're retrieving data for an element you care about or not (and worse, characters between elements). Only store results for `foundCharacter` if you're between a `didStartElement` and `didEndElement` for an element name you care about.
3. Your `didStartElement` is performing the `alloc`, but it is not doing the `init`, too. You should always do the `init` at the same time. You can do additional setting of properties, later, too, but never neglect to call the appropriate `init` method.
4. Your `didEndElement` is retrieving an image from the server. You really should restrict the retrieval of data to just the XML, itself (e.g. in the case of an image, the URL for an image), and not go retrieving additional items from the server. This is especially important as you consider more sophisticated designs, where to minimize memory hits and improve user response time, you may want to employ lazy loading of images, meaning that you want to *only* retrieve the URL from the XML, and let the UI handle if and when images are retrieved. You'll regret doing the image retrieval here as you start doing more sophisticated development in the future.
5. You have an imbalance between the `elementName` checking you're doing in `didStartElement` and `didEndElement`. For all of the elements for which you're retrieving data, you should balance the calls. I know you gave us an example where you were only retrieving a single element from the XML for reasons of simplicity, but in my example below, I'll assume we're retrieving two elements, and the importance of balancing these will become apparent.

For more stylistic observations:

1. By convention, variable names generally start with lowercase letters. Class names generally start with upper case letter. I'm assuming that "EGS" is an established class prefix (e.g. your initials or your firm's acronym), in which case the class names would probably be `EGSBase` and `EGSParser`. By the way, I don't really like the name `EGSBase` because it's a class designed to capture a particular type of XML data, but has a generic name. Either use a generic data structure like a `NSMutableDictionary` or use a custom class and give it a meaningful name (e.g. based upon your references to "products", I'm assuming is is a product, and thus I've renamed it `EGSProduct` in my example below.) Call it whatever you want, but give it a meaningful name if you're using meaningful property names.
2. I notice that you're defining instance variables to back your properties. While that was common convention a year or two ago, latest versions of compilers make this unnecessary, and it's even inadvisable. What you've got works, but it's no longer considered best practice, and is inadvisable (since you can, with a single typo, end up with duplicative instance variables and get very strange behavior). Bottom line, do not define instance variables for your properties. Let the compiler do that for you.
3. I notice you've defined `img` in `egsBase` to be an `IBOutlet`, whereas I find it extremely unlikely that you really have that linked to anything in Interface Builder. First, it's not even a `UIView` descendent (it's a `UIImage`, not a `UIImageView`). Second, `egsBase` is not, itself, a class that you'd be using for an Interface Builder control. Bottom line, this isn't an Interface Builder outlet, so it's just confusing to use `IBOutlet` for `img`.
4. I notice that you are using `retain`. If you're writing ARC code, that should probably be `strong` (even if you're targeting iOS 4.3). If you're not writing ARC code, you have leaks elsewhere in your code.
5. You are manually synthesizing your properties. You can do that, but it's not necessary. Also, best practice nowadays is to have your property's instance variables have a leading underscore. Note, if you omit the `@synthesize` statement, it will synthesize the instance variable with the leading underscore for you. There is some debate in the field as to whether you should use properties exclusively (which I've done below) or use instance variables. I don't care too much, though emerging conventions might lean towards a more extensive use of properties. If you use properties, though (a) [don't use the accessor methods in the initializer and dealloc methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6); and (b) [always use the accessor methods when setting properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW5).
6. I notice that you're defining properties and instance variables (for the parser, in particular) which are private implementation details. The emerging standard here is to limit the properties defined in the .h as those that other classes will need access to. Any other properties which are part of the private implementation of a class are generally defined in private class extension in the .m file itself. It's a minor thing, but if you observe this practice, you'll find it easier to use your classes in the future, where you (or other developers) won't get confused as to what's part of the public interface, and what's part of the private implementation.
7. I notice that your `loadXMLByURL` returns a pointer to the class itself. Generally only classes that `init` objects or create new objects would return a pointer to themselves.
8. Your `loadXMLByURL` should probably should return either (a) a pointer to the `NSMutableArray` that you constructed (returning `nil` on an error); or (b) a `BOOL` success/failure value.
9. For your custom classes, like `EGSBase`, it's useful to write a `description` method, so you can easily `NSLog` them.

---

So, let me give you an example. Let's assume you have an XML that looks like:

```
<Products>
  <products id="0">
    <name>name1</name>
    <img id="1">http://opentestdrive.com/images/first.png</img>
  </products>
  <products id="1">
    <name>name2</name>
    <img id="2">http://opentestdrive.com/images/second.png</img>
  </products>
  <products id="2">
    <name>name3</name>
    <img id="3">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img1.png</img>
  </products>
  <products id="3">
    <name>name4</name>
    <img id="4">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img2.png</img>
    <img-subproduct id="0">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img5.png</img-subproduct>
    <img-subproduct id="1">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img4.png</img-subproduct>
  </products>
  <products id="4">
    <name>name5</name>
    <img id="5">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img3.png</img>
    <img-subproduct id="2">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img3.png</img-subproduct>
    <img-subproduct id="3">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img2.png</img-subproduct>
  </products>
  <products id="5">
    <name>name6</name>
    <img id="6">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img4.png</img>
  </products>
  <products id="6">
    <name>name7</name>
    <img id="7">http://opentestdrive.com/images/img5.png</img>
  </products>
</Products>
```

Then you `EGSProduct` would be defined as follows:

```
//  EGSProduct.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EGSProduct : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageUrlString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *subProducts;

@end
```

and

```
//  EGSProduct.m

#import "EGSProduct.h"

@implementation EGSProduct

- (NSString *)description
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<EGSProduct %p; name='%@'; imageIdentifier='%@'; imageUrlString='%@'; subProducts=", self, self.name, self.imageIdentifier, self.imageUrlString];

    NSMutableArray *subProductDescriptions = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (EGSProduct *subProduct in self.subProducts)
    {
        [subProductDescriptions addObject:[subProduct description]];
    }

    [result appendFormat:@"%@>", [subProductDescriptions componentsJoinedByString:@"; "]];

    return result;
}
@end
```

And your parser might look like:

```
//  EGSParser.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EGSParser : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *products;

- (BOOL)loadXMLByURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

And

```
//  EGSParser.m

#import "EGSParser.h"
#import "EGSProduct.h"

@interface EGSParser () <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSXMLParser *parser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *currentElementContent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) EGSProduct *currentProduct;
@property (nonatomic, strong) EGSProduct *currentSubProduct;

@end

@implementation EGSParser

- (BOOL)loadXMLByURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.parser.delegate = self;
    return [self.parser parse];
}

#pragma mark - NSXMLParser

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    self.products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"products"])
    {
        self.currentProduct = [[EGSProduct alloc] init];
        self.currentProduct.imageIdentifier = attributeDict[@"id"];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"img-subproduct"])
    {
        self.currentSubProduct = [[EGSProduct alloc] init];
        self.currentSubProduct.imageIdentifier = attributeDict[@"id"];
        if (self.currentProduct.subProducts == nil)
        {
            self.currentProduct.subProducts = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        self.currentSubProduct.imageIdentifier = attributeDict[@"id"];
        self.currentElementContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"img"])
    {
        self.currentElementContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    // note, this construct of checking to see if it's nil is actually not needed
    // (since sending a message to a nil object, by definition, does nothing)
    // but I wanted to draw your attention to the fact that we set `currentElementContent`
    // in `didStartElement` and, after saving it in our class, we set it to nil in
    // `didEndElement`

    if (self.currentElementContent != nil)
        [self.currentElementContent appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {
        self.currentProduct.name = self.currentElementContent;      // save the product name
        self.currentElementContent = nil;                           // reset our `currentElementContent`
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"img"])
    {
        self.currentProduct.imageUrlString = [self.currentElementContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        self.currentElementContent = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"img-subproduct"])
    {
        self.currentSubProduct.imageUrlString = self.currentElementContent;
        self.currentElementContent = nil;
        [self.currentProduct.subProducts addObject:self.currentSubProduct];
        self.currentSubProduct = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"products"])
    {
        [self.products addObject:self.currentProduct];
        self.currentProduct = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

To use this class you might do something like the following. If you want to hang on to the XML results after the parser is done (and goes out of scope), you'd just have a class property (in the example below, `xmlProductsResults`. If you want this to be accessible to a variety of different view controllers, you'd save this model data in some shared class (e.g. a model singleton), a property of your app delegate, or pass it as a parameter from view controller to view controller.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://opentestdrive.com/Products.xml"];
EGSParser *parser = [[EGSParser alloc] init];
if ([parser loadXMLByURL:url])
{
    NSLog(@"success; products=%@", parser.products);
    self.xmlProductsResults = parser.products;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"fail");
}
```

---

You could do a lot more with your parser (more robust validation of poorly formed XML files, reporting the errors, if any, back, etc.). Personally, I've done enough XML parsing now that I now employ a very generic parser that can parse most of the XML files I'm dealing with in a few lines, enjoying maximum reuse of the parser class, but that's a bridge too far for this conversation. I've already gone too far in this discussion.

Comment: First of all i have to thank you a lot for giving a detailed description. I have two doubts here, 1. Can you tell what the word `url` refers in line `if ([parser loadXMLByURL:url])`. 2. If  have some sub products in XML say `<img-subProduct>some image link</img-subProduct>` then how can i differentiate it when am retrieving in a view controller. FYI am using this XML http://opentestdrive.com/Products.xml

Comment: @Sabarish I've updated the answer to address your questions and the XML you provided. As an aside, if you have control over the XML, I'd suggest a few changes: 1. You have the outer "Products" tag, but for each element, you then have a tag "products". That really should be "product" (singular). Use plural for the outer wrapper, use singular for the individual items. 2. You probably should wrap your "img-subproducts" in a "subproducts" tag. Whenever you have a list, you should have a wrapper for the list, and elements for the individual items.

Comment: Also note that I've defined the "subproducts" to just be an array of products. If you'd rather define a new custom class for subproducts, that's great too. Works either way. I'll leave the logical change to the code to you. It isn't hard, and you really need to figure out your own way around this code. Never blindly accept code from others (including me), but _really_ understand it yourself.

Comment: Ya, Thank you so much Rob.i understand ill try my best. Am new to iPhone development as am a java,j2ee developer,things here are different even the programming concepts are same. Am lacking in guide for iPhone development.

Comment: rob can you tell me one more thing, as i get the array of data how can i get the individual data from it and assign to variables. for example we have name and image inside the array.i had declared `@property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *firstImage;` when i tried with `parser` am not getting the image inside. how can i get the image of `name1` inside the  `firstimage`

Comment: @Sabarish my point on the `UIImage` was that it doesn't belong in the XML `NSMutableArray`, but rather your view controller would retrieve the image URL string from the XML structure and then set its `UIImageView` accordingly (e.g. `self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:urlFromXml]];`). I'd suggest you play around with it and if you don't figure it out, submit a new question on that topic. But it's probably good to separate the parsing of the XML from the retrieval of the images from the remote server.

Comment: Thank You for your support rob, I'll try as per your suggestion.