# Error on ARC and semantic Issues in iPhone development

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

When trying to Parse the XML file from remote web server, I can parse the data from XML file successfully. From the XML file i tried to retrieve an image URL and assign it to a `UIImageView` for a view controller. here am getting the following Error,

- `ARC Semantic Issue: No known class method for selector 'imageWithContentsOfUrl:'`
- `Sematic Issue: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSString *'`

Below is my code,

```
//My View Controller
[super viewDidLoad];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sample.com/Products.xml"];
 EGSParser *parser = [[EGSParser alloc] init];
// Error in below line( here firstImage is a UIImageView property)
 self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]; 
 if ([parser loadXMLByURL:url]) {
    NSLog(@"success; products=%@",parser.products);
 self.xmlProductsResults = parser.products;
}
else
{
 NSLog(@"Log Fail");
}
```

Kindly Suggest me an idea to solve this.

Comment: self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] ; is absolutely wrong because **url** is not a NSString, its NSUrl itself, so you need to call it directly as  self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfUrl:url];

Comment: @MilKyWaY I changed it but the ARC error resides same no change in it `ARC Semantic Issue: No known class method for selector 'imageWithContentsOfUrl:'`

Comment: Your url points to an xml file. How is that supposed to be displayed as an image?

Comment: @Abizern Can you check this from this answer only i developed and got stuck here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659491/how-to-get-the-xml-parsed-images-into-array-and-use-the-array-in-all-view-contro/14669779#comment20561799_14669779

Comment: because the `+URLWithString:` of `NSURL` expects an `NSString`, you try to feed it with an another `NSURL` objects, of course you've got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

Replace

```
self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

with

```
NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:mydata];
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: I replaced it as you said but am not seeing any image in view controller

Comment: NSLog myData and check if you are getting anything in console

Comment: yes getting values `data <3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e302220 656e636f 64696e67 3d225554 462d3822 3f3e0a3c 50726f64 75637473 3e0a2020 3c70726f 64756374 73206964 3d223022 3e0a2020 203c6e61 6d653e6e 616d6531 3c2f6e61 6d653e0a 2020203c 696d6720 69643d22 3122203e 68747470 3a2f2f6f `

Comment: @Sabarish is your self.firstImage proper? try assigning image directly. I think self.firstImage is not proper allocated or IBOutlet set

Comment: i had set it as IBOutlet only. I had developed by app from this link answer where the parsing works correctly and gets the log output can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659491/how-to-get-the-xml-parsed-images-into-array-and-use-the-array-in-all-view-contro

Comment: Try self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed...] temporary for test, and let me know if you can see image on imageView

Comment: So your issue is currently different, your imageView is not getting initialized properly. Check two things, check in your .xib, whether you have set outlet properly. If not this check that have you reallocated this imageView again somewhere in code?

Comment: am sure PJ, i had connected the IBOutlet `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *firstImage;` correctly with storyboard. and not reallocated anywhere

Comment: Nope, Remains same. Not understanding what mistake am doing

Comment: Do one thing, directly assign image to imageView in xib and check whether you can see that image, let me know

Comment: As you said i directly connected an image in imageview am seeing only a blank screen

Comment: check if there is any view overlaying your imageview, or your imageview frame is getting changed

Comment: change your viewDidLoad to this - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://opentestdrive.com/Products.xml"];
    EGSParser *parser = [[EGSParser alloc] init];
    
    if ([parser loadXMLByURL:url]) {
        self.xmlProductsResults = parser.products;
        EGSProduct *prod = (EGSProduct*)[self.xmlProductsResults objectAtIndex:0];
        NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:prod.imageUrlString]];
        self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:mydata];
    }else
    {NSLog(@"Log Fail");}
}

Comment: And one more thing, learn language first and then start with development, reason is that you were not parsing data and passing xml url directly to that image, how will it work.. :)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked out. As am new to this iPhone development am getting stuck. I just learned from tutorials in net no proper guidance that's my problem. Thanks for your support

Comment: when i was trying to list out the images in a table view how can i show the specific images in table from XML

Comment: sorry again, as i said before am new to iPhone i can understand the concept of what you saying but don't know how to implement it sorry :(

Comment: I cannot implement that for you, you need to search on how to show data from NSmutableArray having class, its actually very simple..

Comment: I did it. Thank you P.J i just need a guidance like this its enough `you need to search on how to show data from NSmutableArray having class`  as i don't know in what term i have to search for in iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Change this line :

```
 self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

to

```
 self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]];
```

Comment: Changed but still the error on ARC `ARC Semantic Issue: No known class method for selector 'imageWithContentsOfUrl:'`

Answer (score 1):

Should work,  just replace

```
self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] ;
```

with

```
self.firstImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

NB: the NSUrl url should be an image url

Comment: I replaced it as you said but am not seeing any image in view controller

Comment: You are not seeing any image because you are sending the wrong thing to the imageview. You are parsing an XML and expecting it to give you an image which is not happening in this case.

Comment: Can you check this link from this answer only i had developed and got stuck here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659491/how-to-get-the-xml-parsed-images-into-array-and-use-the-array-in-all-view-contro

Comment: Dude!! I noticed just now, where is your image? In your code NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sample.com/Products.xml"]; is the link to xml..why don't you parse it yet! in my answer, "url" refers to image url

Comment: ok but i parsed it what you seen in the link i pasted before this comment. You can see the parsing of XML

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, it is `imageWithContentsOfURL:` (capital URL) and not `imageWithContentsOfUrl:`. That's why the class method is not recognized.

Edit: also, it is a method of `CIImage` and not `UIImage`.

Comment: Ok understood it but when after changing am not getting any image in view controller

Comment: I edited my answer. And several people have pointed out that you're trying to get an image from XML content and not from an actual image format?

Comment: yes i can understand it Can you check this link from this answer only i had developed and got stuck here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659491/how-to-get-the-xml-parsed-images-into-array-and-use-the-array-in-all-view-contro